# Is it possible to stream video in ITU-R BT.656 format?

Tags: java, c++, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing

I have to make an application that stream a playlist in the ITU-R BT.656 video format. Frankly speaking it's my first time hearing about this format. It seems to be used for DV streaming. I have been googling around for hours and so far the only BT656 encoders i found are hardware one. Is it possible to do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BT.656 data stream is a sequence of 8-bit or 10-bit words, transmitted at a rate of 27 Mbyte/s.

Essentially this is a digitized raw video. While conceptually, streaming this might not be impossible, you cannot really afford to stream at **27 MBps**. If indeed that is what you need to do, converting each frame into a BMP and sending them one after the other would be equivalent. If you are getting this from some raw video source, it is best to encode with reasonable standard MPEG format and bit rate and stream it.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-R_BT.656